# Is there a decent application for personal finances that support multiple currencies on OSX?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'd like to keep track of my finances better and wondering what good options there are out there. Preferably something that isn't geared towards Americans as my dollars tend to be Singapore ones and it'd be nice if also could track my finances in other countries in their native currency. :)

Answer (score 2):

[iBank](http://www.iggsoftware.com/ibank/) sure does:

> **Go global.** Just like your Mac, iBank works worldwide. With multi-currency support, you can set a default currency for any account, download exchange rates and calculate transfers between accounts automatically. iBank supports localization for British English, and now includes full French language support as well.

[MoneyWell](http://nothirst.com/moneywell/) does as well:

> **Transaction-Level Exchange Rates**
>   Do you bank in multiple currencies? MoneyWell has you covered. You can track your spending in your primary currency while having accounts in several other currencies and store both amounts in each transaction.

Answer (score 0):

[Squirrel](http://squirrelapp.com/l-en/mac/index.html) does as well.

It's got a clean interface and is easy to work with. If you're on Lion, you might want to grab the version from the Mac App Store (0.8.8 at the time of writing) instead, but that one does not currently support syncing with the iPhone version of Squirrel. iCloud based syncing will be in a coming update.

The version on the web site (0.8.7) has some small issues on Lion but can sync. It works like a charm on Snow Leopard.